# Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core

I've encountered this exception when trying to call `DbContext.Database.Migrate`. 
Looks like this is not very common on the net (or Google has some trouble searching it?). The only possible cause I could find is due to `in-memory` database or some kind of provider that is not `relational`?

But when debugging, I can see that the provider name is `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore`, I'm using `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.19.30` (to connect to an Oracle Database). So this is confusing now, I'm not sure what's wrong here.

The code is simple like this:

```
_dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: To be clear, *Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider* is the error message you want to understand?

Comment: @APC no, more exactly I'm having that issue blocking me from continuing coding. Maybe we need to understand it first before solving it. But I think it is fairly understandable, somehow the `DbContext` is not considered as `relational` (such as `in-memory db`). However as you can see what I post in my question, the `provider name` is `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` and I don't think it's not relational (the connection string points to my `Oracle Db` - from a real server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exception thrown is very confusing. I had to look into the source code for `RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService` via which I can see somehow the `TService` is not loaded. That service type may be contained in some dll (the most possible one is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll`, if that dll is not loaded correctly, it will throw the described exception.

Actually in my case, that dll is loaded with wrong version (2.2.4.0 is loaded whereas the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version is 2.2.6.0). All this happened while I try to load them dynamically (not tightly referencing them in projects).

Comment: The same happened to me when I was upgrading EF Core from 3.1 to 5.0. I've manually removed old packages and it started to work.